# Java stream - Invoke a method from each object in a list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have a List of Car class - List
I want to iterate it and invoke a method. e.g. set().
How can I do it with stream()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you don't even need a `Stream` :

```
List<Car> cars = ...;
cars.forEach(Car::set);
```

You could do it with a `Stream` if you insist :

```
cars.stream().forEach(Car::set);
```